# Why is x*cos(a)+y*sin(a)=r used instead of a=-b*x+y for hough tranform?

Tags: image-processing, hough-transform

It seems the other formula would have the same effect of voting for lines and be easier to calculate and observe. So why is the more complicated formula used instead?

Comment: You want a parameterization that's at least bounded with respect to line orientation. Slope is not. Near-vertical lines have near-infinite slope. Infinity does not play well with finite precision arithmetic.

Comment: makes a lot of sense, thanks

Comment: A quick read of [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform#Theory) would have answered your question as well: "In general, the straight line y = mx + b can be represented as a point (b, m) in the parameter space. However, vertical lines pose a problem. They would give rise to unbounded values of the slope parameter m. Thus, for computational reasons, Duda and Hart[5] proposed the use of the Hesse normal form r = x cos θ +y sin θ, [...]."

Comment: By the way, I highly recommend reading [Hart's description of the history of the Hough transform](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f7e8/cbca97de34fd3695e538e164a1b40d27b04e.pdf). Hart is the person that came up with the modern form of the transform.